# XCode performance measurement

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, performance, cocoa-touch

My app's animations are a little sluggish when I test it on my device (it runs fine in the simulator). I have some suspicions about the cause, but before I start tuning I would like to be able to benchmark where I'm starting from, and repeat similar tests after each change.

What should I be measuring, and how? It feels like the frames per second would be the most useful measure for what I'm experiencing, but I'm not really sure where to start.

Comment: One stupid simple technique is to wait until the app is in a "sluggish" phase and then press the "pause" button in the simulator/debugger.  Examine the stack and see what it's doing.  (You may need to examine the stacks of several threads.)  Repeat this 5-10 times, and see if you tend to hit the same methods repeatedly.  Sometimes it will be obvious what's slowing things down (eg, you're always in a search loop).  Not very rigorous, but simple and often effective, and it's easier to sample just the "sluggish" periods this way than when using other techniques.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Instruments.  You can launch it directly from Xcode using Product -> Profile (Command-I).